# SQL Relational Database Design

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

If you could fully explain, or point me in the direction I would greatly appreciate it.

I am trying to create a DB that stores businesses and list them as activities to do around the local area. In tier form, I want to store them as:

Activity Category

- Activity Sub-Category
- Activity
- Where activity category would be: Indoor, Outdoor, Arts...etc
- Where activity sub-category would be: Aquarium, Museum, Parks ...etc
- Where activity would be listings of the sub-category: Aquarium of
  Florida, British Museum..

Say I used the 3 names above as my tables, what would be the proper relation? In the ActivitySubCategory table, would I create a FK with a relation to ActivityCategoryID Pk?
Would I create a FK in the Activity table that relates to the ActivitySubCategoryID PK?

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  It will teach you the fundamentals.  The rest is thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems likely that you will end up with a many to many relationship (there are many subcategories to arts for instance, but the British Musesum might be in arts and in Indoor), you should add a Join or Link table that contains just the ids values from both the activity table and the subactivity table. Make sure to use both as the PK so you can only get each combo entered once.

Comment: I was going into this thinking one to many, you just saved me a headache and a few hours. Thank you very much for your response and for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Does each activity have one and only one category?  My proposal is to create an Activity table, and then a Category table with a ParentCategory column - which would be a self-referencing join.

If an activity can have one and only one category then a simple FK relationship is all that's needed.  If not then you'd need a 3rd table as an associative.

Comment: Yes, each activity will only have one category. Thank you for your proposal and for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the foreign keys as you suggested:

- FK from ActivitySubCategory to ActivityCategory PK
- FK from Activity to ActivitySubCategory PK

However, this would limit your Activity to only one sub-category.  If you need to associate Activities to more than one sub-category, then you should create a lookup table with foreign keys to both Activities and ActivitySubCategories.

If you envision any more possible levels of categories, you could create a single ActivityCategories table that has a FK to itself.  This would be a parent/child relationship between rows of the same table, so you might want to create ActivityCategories.ParentKey which refers to ActivityCategories.PK.  A top-level ActivityCategory would have a NULL ParentKey.

In addition, I recommend creating indexes on your foreign keys.  For example, create in index on Activity.ActivitySubCategoryKey and on ActivitySubCategory.ActivityCategoryKey.  If you do not do this, deletions of activity categories or sub-categories could take a very long time.

Comment: The first post made me realize exactly what you just said about limiting the Activity to only one sub-category. I am unsure of the ActivityCategories table you mentioned that has a FK to itself, but conceptually that does that does make scene to me. Do you have any resources off the top of your head to provide me with reading further? Thank you for your time Mr. Williams.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other answers and give you an insight into how I approach this sort of problem.

The database structure is the **last** thing I think about. At the end of the day, the RDMS is a data store - its where things are kept when you are not using them.

Start out by thinking about the real world problem you are modeling. Real world objects will be modeled as software objects - what properties are essential and what methods are needed to make those objects evolve. Once you have this structure clear the database schema falls out naturally.

For your problem you have 2 real world things; activities and categories. Ignoring their unique properties, consider how these objects interact.

**Activity**

- Is an activity always in a category?
- Only one category?
- Can it move between categories?
- If so, does it need to know where it has been?
- And when?
- Will it always be part of a sub-category or can it be attached directly to a category?

**Category**

- Will there only ever be 2 levels in the hierarchy or could there be sub-sub-categories?
- Will sub-categories only ever be part of one category?
- Can they move between categories?
- If so, does it need to know where it has been?
- And when?

Comment: As soon as I get 15 reputation, I am marking this up. This is the first problem, I have not been asking myself the right questions; guess it's back to Code Complete or some other "how to think like a programmer" book. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @KRob  I see you with a reputation of 16.  Try to keep up, will you. :^)